# ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS #12 wallet

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We are facing connectivity issues, while trying to connect via sqlplus from our Solaris server to Oracle Cloud.

Error: ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS #12 wallet

Comment: When you say "Oracle Cloud", am I right to assume that you're referring to an Autonomous Database?

Comment: Yes, Autonomous Data Warehouse Cloud (ADWC).

Comment: Post installation of Oracle client 12.1, we have tried to connect to cloud from sqlplus, we are getting this error. ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-29106: Cannot import PKCS #12 wallet

If using the client less than 12 version
    Bug:  23335686 -> update Your client

> ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

Check Your Client Server sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora file

- sqlnet.ora: check  WALLET_LOCATION -> DIRECTORY
- tnsnames.ora: check TNSNAME

Comment: am able to tnsping with tns_entry.
Updated the sqlnet.ora with the exact wallet location: check WALLET_LOCATION -> DIRECTORY

Still not resolved, same error.

Answer (score 0):

for me it helped:

```
# new lines in listener.ora
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
WALLET_LOCATION =
  (SOURCE =
    (METHOD = FILE)
    (METHOD_DATA =
      (DIRECTORY = /opt/oracle/somewhere/hidden/wallets)
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle
```